# Xpath accents in the source

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

I'm using google spreadsheet to extract a few book descriptions from an html page.

A1 contains the ISBN number and in another cell I have this `=importXML("http://www.ibs.it/code/"&A1& "/scheda/libro.html","(//span[@class='tcorpotesto'])[1]")`.

It works but something is wrong with the accents. For example on http://www.ibs.it/code/9788823503298/hornby-nick/febbre-90ordm.html one of the words is 'Perché' but the scraped text in the cell is 'Perch?'

How can I fix this? It's the same problem with all the accented characters.

Comment: XPath itself is encoding-agnostic -- or, rather, it expects to be run against data which contains strings composed of characters rather than bytes, already decoded from their form on-disk. In short, this is less a generic XPath question and more something that requires some diving into implementation details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The document at http://www.ibs.it/code/9788823503298/hornby-nick/febbre-90ordm.html uses ISO-8859-1 encoding.

Google uses UTF-8.

It appears that their implementation of importXML() doesn't perform character set translation preserving these characters correctly. You could provide your own proxy / web service that runs translation inline, or file a ticket requesting a fix from upstream.